# Laravel 5.4 Class 'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider' not found After i set app:name

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I need your help with newbie problem.

On my local project, i use command `php artisan app:name xyz`

Then I push it into production and there i have an error:

> production.ERROR:
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class
>   'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider' not found in
>   /var/www/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:612

How can I fix it?

Comment: If I may, it's not recommended to rename your App name. It's ok if you work on a single project, but if you switch between different projects with different names, it becomes a mess. Just my two cents ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to run `config:cache` command, if you can't delete file `bootstrap/cache/config.php` and then re-run `config:cache` command and everything will be fine again.